# I can't select next li node

Tags: jquery

I have the the following HTML :

```
<ul id="ResultatRechercheRapideInteret">
    <div class="ETResultatRechercheType">Personnes</div>
    <li class="globalSearch"></li>
    <li class="globalSearch globalSearchSelected"></li>
    <div class="ETResultatRechercheType">Intérêts</div>
    <li class="globalSearch"></li>
</ul>
```

and when I try to execute the following jquery instruction my third li doesn't get the globalSearchSelected class

```
$(".globalSearchSelected:last").next('li').addClass("globalSearchSelected");
```

Ideas ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your markup is invalid. The only valid child for an `ul` is a `li` element. That being said, for selecting the first next sibling that matches the selector, you can use `nextAll` and `first` methods. `next` only selects the very next element (*if it matches the specified selector*).

```
$(".globalSearchSelected:last")
    .nextAll('.globalSearch') // all the next `.globalSearch` siblings
    .first() // the first matched element
    .addClass("globalSearchSelected");
```